# How to use pentaho data integration for data migration

Tags: pentaho

i am new for pentaho,

i have create input mysql and have validator and i want to migrate from mySql to postgreSql

my question is how to drag from input to validators and to output ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the origin step, pops up a line with options, one of them is to create a new hop to another step.

You also have the option of adding another step by double clicking the new step class in the design panel, if you have a step selected in the canvas, the new step is added with the hop created from the selected step to the new one.